# Cannot build and insert my version of "uio_pci_generic" module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

To make sure I understand the process of building a UIO driver I thought
I would take the existing code for uio_pci_generic.c make some changes
to differentiate it from the original call it uioJ_pci_generic.c and see if I can build and insert this module into a Fedora 17 system.

These are the changes I made to the original uio_pci_generic to produce my
test module uioJ_pci_generic which I was unable to insert into a
running kernel. Please enlighten me (grovel,grovel,.....)

To differentiate my version from the original I changed this in the original :

```
gdev->info.name = "uio_pci_generic";
```

to this :

```
gdev->info.name = "uioJ_pci_generic";
```

Also change the original :

```
static struct pci_driver uioJ_pci_driver = {
    .name = "uio_pci_generic",
    .id_table = NULL, /* only dynamic id's */
    .probe = probe,
    .remove = remove,
};
```

to :

```
static struct pci_driver uioJ_pci_driver = {
    .name = "uioJ_pci_generic",
    .id_table = NULL, /* only dynamic id's */
    .probe = probe,
    .remove = remove,
};
```

I also modified the DRIVER_AUTHOR from the original :

```
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR   "Michael S. Tsirkin <mst@redhat.com>"
```

to :

```
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR   "Neddy Seagoon <mst@redhat.com>"
```

Also modified the DRIVER_DESC from the original :

```
#define DRIVER_DESC "Generic UIO driver for PCI 2.3 devices"
```

to :

```
#define DRIVER_DESC "Mother : Generic UIO driver (with comments)for PCI 2.3 devices"
```

Here is the modified version :

```
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uio_driver.h>

#define DRIVER_VERSION  "0.01.0"
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR   "Neddy Seagoon <mst@redhat.com>"
#define DRIVER_DESC "Mother : Generic UIO driver (with comments)for PCI           2.3 devices"

struct uio_pci_generic_dev {
    struct uio_info info;
    struct pci_dev *pdev;
};

static inline struct uio_pci_generic_dev *
to_uio_pci_generic_dev(struct uio_info *info)
{
    return container_of(info, struct uio_pci_generic_dev, info);
}

/* Interrupt handler. Read/modify/write the command register to disable
 * the interrupt. */
static irqreturn_t irqhandler(int irq, struct uio_info *info)
{
    static int count = 0;
    pr_info("In UIO handler, count=%d\n", ++count);

    struct uio_pci_generic_dev *gdev = to_uio_pci_generic_dev(info);

    if (!pci_check_and_mask_intx(gdev->pdev))
    return IRQ_NONE;


    /* UIO core will signal the user process. */
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int probe(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    struct uio_pci_generic_dev *gdev;
    int err;

    err = pci_enable_device(pdev);
    if (err) {
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "%s: pci_enable_device failed: %d\n",
        __func__, err);
    return err;
    }

    pr_info("probe : pci_enable_device() Success\n");

    if (!pdev->irq) {
        dev_warn(&pdev->dev, "No IRQ assigned to device: "
            "no support for interrupts?\n");
        pci_disable_device(pdev);
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    pr_info("probe : using IRQ=%d\n", pdev->irq);


    if (!pci_intx_mask_supported(pdev)) {
        err = -ENODEV;
        goto err_verify;
    }    

    gdev = kzalloc(sizeof(struct uio_pci_generic_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!gdev) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto err_alloc;
    }

    gdev->info.name = "uioJ_pci_generic";
    gdev->info.version = DRIVER_VERSION;
    gdev->info.irq = pdev->irq;
    gdev->info.irq_flags = IRQF_SHARED;
    gdev->info.handler = irqhandler;
    gdev->pdev = pdev;

    err = uio_register_device(&pdev->dev, &gdev->info);
    if (err)
        goto err_register;
    pr_info("probe : uio_register_device() Success : %d\n", err);

    pci_set_drvdata(pdev, gdev);
    return 0;

    err_register:
    pr_info("probe : uio_register_device() Failed : %d\n", err);
    kfree(gdev);
    err_alloc:
    err_verify:
    pr_info("probe : pci_disable_device()\n");

    pci_disable_device(pdev);
    return err;
}

static void remove(struct pci_dev *pdev)
{
    struct uio_pci_generic_dev *gdev = pci_get_drvdata(pdev);

    pr_info("remove()\n");

    uio_unregister_device(&gdev->info);
    pci_disable_device(pdev);
    kfree(gdev);
}

static struct pci_driver uioJ_pci_driver = {
    .name = "uioJ_pci_generic",
    .id_table = NULL, /* only dynamic id's */
    .probe = probe,
    .remove = remove,
};

module_pci_driver(uioJ_pci_driver);
MODULE_VERSION(DRIVER_VERSION);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
```

Here are the steps I took to build and insert the module :

Step 1 : Build the module.

```
obj-m += uioJ_pci_generic.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

# ls -l


-rw-r--r--. 1 james james  13943 Jun 14 11:09 uioJ_pci_generic.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 james james  13943 Jun 12 23:12 uioJ_pci_generic.c~
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root  120924 Jun 27 22:41 uioJ_pci_generic.ko
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root     415 Jun 27 22:41 uioJ_pci_generic.mod.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root   42288 Jun 27 22:41 uioJ_pci_generic.mod.o
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root   79592 Jun 27 22:41 uioJ_pci_generic.o
```

Note that the driver uioJ_pci_generic is not executable, no 'x' in the permissions (Why ???)

Step 2 : Copy uioJ_pci_generic.ko the uio directory

```
# cp uioJ_pci_generic.ko /lib/modules/...../drivers/uio
  cp: overwrite `/lib/modules/..../drivers/uio/uioJ_pci_generic.ko'? y

# depmod -a
```

Step 3 : Now check module

```
# ls -l
total 168
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root   4792 May  7  2012 uio_aec.ko
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root   4640 May  7  2012 uio_cif.ko
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 120924 Jun 10 13:52 uioJ_pci_generic.ko
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root  14212 May  7  2012 uio.ko
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root   4440 May  7  2012 uio_pci_generic.ko
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root   5516 May  7  2012 uio_sercos3.ko
```

Note that my uioJ_pci_generic.ko has no 'x' permission but the original does.
(Why ???)

Step 4 : Get the module info for uioJ_pci_generic :

```
# modinfo uioJ_pci_generic

filename:       /lib/modules../kernel/drivers/uio/uioJ_pci_generic.ko
description:    Mother : Generic UIO driver (with comments)for PCI 2.3 devices
author:         Neddy Seagoon <mst@redhat.com>
license:        GPL v2
version:        0.01.0
srcversion:     7780AD87F53B831688C0CFD
depends:        
vermagic:       3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE SMP mod_unload 686 
# 
#
```

Compared to the original :

```
# modinfo uio_pci_generic 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE/kernel/drivers/uio/uio_pci_generic.ko
description:    Generic UIO driver for PCI 2.3 devices
author:         Michael S. Tsirkin <mst@redhat.com>
license:        GPL v2
version:        0.01.0
srcversion:     24D140D89C561428A72FF39
depends:        uio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE SMP mod_unload 686 
#
```

Note the difference : uio_pci_generic depends on uio, uioJ_pci_generic does not.

Step 5 : insert the modules

```
# modprobe uio
# modprobe uio_pci_generic

then I saw this in /var/log/messages:
Jun 27 23:33:46 localhost kernel: [ 3566.198890] Generic UIO driver for  PCI 2.3 devices version: 0.01.0

then I tried to insert the uioJ_pci_generic version

# modprobe uioJ_pci_generic 
but I saw nothing further in /var/log/messages in response to this.
```

If the uioJ_pci_generic module did get loaded properly the string
"Mother : Generic UIO driver (with comments)for PCI 2.3 devices" would have been printed in /var/log/messages

The standard uio_pci_generic was built differently (correctly) than my version.
What is wrong with my sequence of steps to build my uioJ_pci_generic ?

I puzzle you !
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you change anything in kconfig?

Comment: I changed nothing in kconfig.

Comment: Recheck because it has to show _depends on uio_ at least in modinfo

Comment: I have checked again - uioJ_pci_generic does not depend on uio. But it should ! Does this suggest I am missing some subtlety in the build process?